# Docker Postgres connection refused

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to run a docker container that contains postgres and access its localhost on my application. However, I am getting this error:

```
UserRDD$ docker run -i --rm -e PGPASSWORD=12qw --network=host postgres:10.9 psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres -d postgres -f -

psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

The same code seems to be running for someone else. Not sure what I am missing.

Can you please let me know what I am missing. Been trying to struggle with it for the last 3 hours.

Thanks

Comment: How are you running the database?  Do you _need_ to run the client in a container, or can you install the PostgreSQL command-line tools and just run `psql` from the host?

Comment: @DavidMaze I guess, that he has postgres in docker and the problem get access to container from localhost

Comment: Attach the result of the docker ps command

Comment: @MaximKasyanov yes you are right. I'm trying to access postgres inside the docker container. docker ps returns empty because the docker isn't started because of this failure. I did however, just run `docker run -i --rm -e PGPASSWORD=12qw --network=host postgres:10.9` without the second argument and that started the docker. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command with port mapping to expose container port to localhost `-p <host_port>:<container_port>`

```
docker run  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12qw  -e POSTGRES_DB=stack -p 1111:5432 -d postgres
```

After that, you could access to this postgres instance on `localhost:1111` port

```
psql -h localhost -p 1111 -U postgres -d stack
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is **Postgres** DB is not running as you override the default `CMD` which just start Postgres client (`psql`), not DB server. for DB server the argument should be `postgres`.

```
docker run -i --rm -e PGPASSWORD=12qw --network=host postgres:10.9 postgres
```

As your command does not start Postgres server, but there is only Postgres client that trying to connect with localhost of the container but the Postgres server is not running. it will make sense like

```
docker run -i --rm  postgres:10.9 psql -h remote-server -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres
```

To run postgres server you only need

```
docker run  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12qw  -e POSTGRES_DB=test -p 5432:5432 -d postgres:10.9
```

then connect with db after DB is up.

Another important thing any argument that is passed to run command will be treated as an argument to postgres server, for example

```
docker run -i --rm  postgres:10.9  --version
```